# How to force Reactjs reload or alterative solution to current scenario

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am fairly new to React so please bear with me.
I have got an array of records (todoItem) each with its own objects that I am display in UI elements with no issues. One of these objects is {todoItem.status} of type Boolean that isbeing used in a checkbox field.

Code extracts:

```
/../
 const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(0);
.../

/...
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodoData(); // extract data from DB
  }, [status]);
.../

/...
<input
 id={todoItem.id}
 defaultChecked={todoItem.status}
 type='checkbox'
 className='rounded w-4 h-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600'
 onClick={() => {
   console.log('CURRENT STATUS', todoItem.status);
   const statusUpdate = !todoItem.status;                         
   updateTodoData(todoItem.id, statusUpdate);
   console.log('STATUS UPDATED:', statusUpdate);
   setRefresh((prevState) => prevState + 1);  // should refresh with this call, but dont     
   //location.reload();                       // works, but looks bad
 }}
../
/>
```

Expection:
On checkbox click, DB updates, makes use of useState() "setRefresh((prevState) => prevState + 1)" to reload component. With the updated values of {todoItem.status} UI will be updated accordingly.

Reality:
No reload is initiated by useState() "setRefresh((prevState) => prevState + 1)", {todoItem.status} value stays the same, which means UI dont change. Unless I use location.reload() which I dont want becuase it looks bad and its bad practice.

What am I doing wrong or what can I do diffrent to get component to reload.
And yes I have gone though all the suggested questiosn already.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my problem.
useState() was actually working fine.
In dev mode Reactjs will load twice because it is set to strict-mode.
There is a logical reason for this occurrence, but it was not working for me.
This second reload caused all kinds of problems.

strict-mode can be disabled by removing 'use strict' at the top, in your main application index file or like in my case updating the tsconfig.json file. `"strict": false`